# Ubuntu 12.10 apache 2.4.6 AH00141 Could not initialize random number generator

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10. I installed php5.5.9 with apache 2.4.6 from ppa ondrej/php5
Installation was successful, without any errors. But I have problem with running apache
I'm running

`apache2ctl configtest`

and the result is:

`[Tue Mar 04 18:11:40.473001 2014] [:crit] [pid 9696] (2)No such file or directory: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.`

I searched in google but only solution that I found was for Windows. Any tips how I can solve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if your random generator is missing. Please check if these files exists: **/dev/urandom** and **/dev/random**. If not, you should be able to fix this by using the following commands:
`cd /dev`
`sudo /sbin/MAKEDEV std`

You can read more about the random generator in the [Ubuntu Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/man4/random.4.html)